# Merge rows that have the same value in a specific column without change/sorted lines and use the first non-empty value for each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The line sequence cannot be modified or sorted (I tried using `group` but that modified/sorted the sequence when using `id` column as a reference).

In all my dataframes I have a reference column called `id` and I will concatenate them to maintain the sequence of importance of the data, the most important dataframe comes first and the least important ones below.

I want to merge all rows that have the same value in the reference column.

However, in the resulting merged row, the value in each column should be the first "non-empty" value of each column, whether it is `numpy.nan`, `''` string or already imported from a CSV file without a value.

If there is no value in any of the rows to be merged, then in that case, the column should be empty.

I was not able to understand how to achieve this result. I tried some simple approaches but they did not work out positively.

Base code:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

new_df_one = pd.DataFrame({
    'identity':['1234','9999','1111'],
    'column_a':['hhhh','aaaa',''],
    'column_b':['hhhh',np.nan,np.nan],
    'column_c':[np.nan,'aaaa',''],
    'column_d':['hhhh','aaaa','']
})

new_df_two = pd.DataFrame({
    'identity':['1234','9999'],
    'column_a':[np.nan,np.nan],
    'column_b':[np.nan,np.nan],
    'column_c':[np.nan,np.nan],
    'column_d':['zzzz',np.nan]
})

original_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'identity':['1234','1111'],
    'column_a':[np.nan,'gggg'],
    'column_b':[np.nan,'gggg'],
    'column_c':['hhhh','gggg'],
    'column_d':['hhhh','gggg']
})

concat_df = pd.concat([new_df_one, new_df_two, original_df], ignore_index=True)
```

I tried using group in some ways with agg but I couldn't get the desired result, because either they end up merging values if they exist on more than one line or they define the first value so it doesn't deviate from empty values:

```python
#test 1
result_df = concat_df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: ''.join(x)).reset_index()

#test 2
result_df = concat_df.groupby('id').first().reset_index()
```

My expected result is:

```
identity column_a column_b column_c column_d
    1234     hhhh     hhhh     hhhh     hhhh
    9999     aaaa              aaaa     aaaa
    1111     gggg     gggg     gggg     gggg
```

Comment: Which dataframe defines the required output row order?

Comment: And what is the ordering of the dataframes? i.e. which is "first" (and "second" and last)?

Comment: Hello @Nick , if there were no empty values, the sequence of importance would be exactly the same as doing ```concat_df.drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='first')```, but if there are columns with empty values, it is necessary to collect the value of the first one non-empty row with the same ```id```.

Comment: So does that mean new_df_one, new_df_two, original_df?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @Nick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing all empty string `''` with `nan` and use `first`:

```
(concat_df.replace('', np.nan)
    .groupby('identity', as_index=False, sort=False).first()
)
```

Output:

```
  identity column_a column_b column_c column_d
0     1234     hhhh     hhhh     hhhh     hhhh
1     9999     aaaa     None     aaaa     aaaa
2     1111     gggg     gggg     gggg     gggg
```